# How to invert a regular expression in pandas filter function

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe `df` (which is actually just the last lines of a much larger one):

```
                           count
gene                            
WBGene00236788                56
WBGene00236807                 3
WBGene00249816                12
WBGene00249825                20
WBGene00255543                 6
__no_feature            11697881
__ambiguous                 1353
__too_low_aQual                0
__not_aligned                  0
__alignment_not_unique         0
```

I can use `filter`'s `regex` option to get only the lines starting with two underscores:

```
df.filter(regex="^__", axis=0)
```

This returns the following:

```
                           count
gene                            
__no_feature            11697881
__ambiguous                 1353
__too_low_aQual                0
__not_aligned                  0
__alignment_not_unique         0
```

Actually, what I want is to have the complement: Only those lines that do not start with two underscores.

I can do it with another regular expression: `df.filter(regex="^[^_][^_]", axis=0)`.

**Is there a way to more simply specify that I want the inverse of the initial regular expression?**

**Is such regexp-based filtering efficient?**

#### Edit: Testing some proposed solutions

`df.filter(regex="(?!^__)", axis=0)` and `df.filter(regex="^\w+", axis=0)` both return all lines.

According to the `re` module documentation, the `\w` special character actually includes the underscore, which explains the behaviour of the second expression.

I guess that the first one doesn't work because the `(?!...)` applies on what follows a pattern. Here, "^" should be put outside, as in the following proposed solution:

`df.filter(regex="^(?!__).*?$", axis=0)` works.

So does `df.filter(regex="^(?!__)", axis=0)`.

Comment: `(?!^__)` might be what you're looking for. Or, maybe even better: `^\w+`

Comment: You could just take the indices from the data frame with underscores and exclude them from the original data frame. The "new" indices could be gathered like: `[idx for idx in original_df.index if idx not in underscore_df.index]`

Comment: That has to many zero matches. Better: `^(?!__).*?$`

Comment: @RobinKoch: The lazy dot star is very expensive and not needed here.

Comment: I had tried `(?!^__)` after having a look at the `re` module documentation, and it happens that this doesn't work: all lines are kept.

Comment: I just tried the `^\w+` and it also keeps all lines. I guess the regexps in pandas are not the same as the ones in the `re` module.

Comment: I actually read the documentation more carefully now, and I think I understood the problems with the solutions proposed by @Jan
See the edits in my post.

Comment: `(?!^__)` selects all lines, because it matches every empty string that's  not followed by a new line and two underscores. So basically everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matching all lines with no two leading underscores:

`^(?!__)`

`^` matches the beginning of the line
`(?!__)`makes sure the line (what follows the preceding `^` match) does not begin with two underscores

**Edit:**
dropped the `.*?$` since it's not necessary to filter the lines.

Comment: The lazy dot star is very expensive and not needed here

Comment: `^(?!__)` works too and avoids the possibly expensive star.

Comment: Right, I thought about matching the line instead of filtering.

Comment: Can someone explain why the grouping parentheses are needed here?

Comment: @JazzWeisman They belong to the "negative lookahead". Basically `(?!pattern)` allows to find matches that aren't followed by `pattern`. If you omit the parentheses The expression gets a completely different meaning: `^?!__`would match any `!__` (possibly including the beginning of the line, but since it's a zero-width-character it makes not difference).

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem but I wanted to filter the columns. Thus I am using axis=1 but concept should be similar.

```
df.drop(df.filter(regex='my_expression').columns,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities here:

```
(?!^__) # a negative lookahead
        # making sure that there are no underscores right at the beginning of the line
```

Or:

```
^\w+  # match word characters, aka a-z, A-Z, 0-9 at least once
```

Comment: Strangely, neither of these work: all lines get selected.

Comment: I think I understood why: see the edits at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Invert select of multiple columns (A, B, C).

```
df.filter(regex=r'^(?!(A_|B_.*_|C_.*_.*_))',axis='columns')
```